# fusion builder missing from custom post editor

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I appreciate all help in advance. I am building a fairly customised website using Avada theme and BNE Flyouts.

I need to be able to enable the Avada's Fusion Builder when editing flyouts, so it can be edited in drag and drop mode.

I have tried enabling both for custom post types, but still when I go to edit the flyout, none of the wysiwyg editors show: https://www.screencast.com/t/5dQ5hdDew3a

I checked in the database and I am certain that flyouts are actually stored as posts: https://www.screencast.com/t/OMDsavM5o

Question:
 - Is there a way to enable fusion builder on every editor window that I open, whatever is the post type
 - Can I force particular post type to open fusion builder on certain post type? How do I determine the post type name for functions.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually found a solution o plugins developer support page, but it will work with small modification for any other plugin:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type ) {
if( 'bne_flyout' === $post_type ) {
    $args['public'] = true;
}

return $args;   
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dashboard look on the left for fusion builder.  Under that option look for settings.  On the resulting page scroll to the bottom and look for "post types"  Check the box next to the post types you want to enable fusion builder on and then click the "save settings" button a bit farther down.  Volia.

Comment: i already did that, that is why I am asking the question:) 
Fusion builder, even though all post types are selected, does not open when I edit Flyouts.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen on the related question linked below, go to Avada Options > Builder Options scroll down to Post Types and check the box for your post type.

There's a screenshot of the relevant navegation on the related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65777098/avada-builder-custom-post-types